# 'answer' type has "unchanged in unsafe filters" listed for the wrong field

Tags: bug, documentation

http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer says the `can_flag` field is *unchanged in unsafe filters*. It's probably meant for the field above it: `body_markdown`.

Comment: Makes you wonder what the point of having "safe" filters is, if all the body fields are "unchanged in unsafe filters".  Those fields being the ones that are especially of concern for script (and HTML) injection.